# How to search for a resource recursively in the classpath

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I have a xyz.properties file which can be put anywhere in the classpath and the java code is expected to load that properties file -

I am aware that Class.getResource(String resource) and ClassLoader.getResource(String resource) need relative and absolute paths for the resource.

How can I search for this file anywhere recursively in the classpath ? - Is there a library that does it ?

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream searches for the file on the classpath

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
   InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourProp.properties");
    prop.load(stream);
```

Comment: The above loader.getResourceAsStream("yourProp.properties") only works when yourProp.properties is directly under resources/ ... it wont work if its under resources/files/yourProp.properties ... I want to search it anywhere in the classpath

Comment: loader.getResourceAsStream("yourProp.properties") takes absolute path so it wont do it..

Comment: well if your classpath includes the path till resources, yes it will search it under resource folder. Yo need to give the path if you want to search under any cascaded resource folder .For example :- loader.getResourceAsStream("files/yourProp.properties");

Comment: I was looking for sth like - org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver ..
docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

Comment: In that case, I suggest `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` :-)

Comment: :-) yeah - i couldn't write the answer to my own question because I have less than 10 reputation .. so I just replied to this comment :)